# Connection between ideals in a ring and ring with associated unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(A,+,\cdot)$ be a ring. In the set $A\times \mathbb{Z}$ we define:
$$ (a,k)+'(b,l)=(a+b,k+l),$$
$$(a,k)\cdot ' (b,l):=(ab+la+kb,kl)$$
for $a,b \in A$, $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$. 
Then $(A\times \mathbb{Z}, +',\cdot') $   is the unitary ring.

Is there connection between ideals in $A$ and ideals in $A\times \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: What is $P$?  Is that supposed to be $A\times \mathbb Z$?

Comment: Sorry.  It should be $A\times Z$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, $A\times\mathbb{Z}$ is *not* a good notation for the ring (known as the Dorroh extension of $A$), because $A\times\mathbb{Z}$ has a natural ring structure which is not the one we are using here. So it's best to call it something else. It's common to use $A^1$.

Second: There is a canonical embedding $\varphi\colon A\to A^1$ given by $\varphi(a)=(a,0)$. Under this embedding, you can verify rather easily that $\varphi(I) = \{(x,0)\mid x\in I\}$ is a left (resp. right, two-sided) ideal of $A^1$ whenever $I$ is a left (resp. right, two-sided) ideal of $A$.

If $J$ is a left (resp. right, two-sided) ideal of $A^1$, then both the intersection with $\varphi(A)$ and the projection onto $A$ are left (resp. right, two-sided) ideals of $A$.